# Pointer being freed was not allocated [Swift]

Tags: swift, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to read long length String in TCP socket connection . 
For reading short length string it is working fine . but when i am trying to send long length base64 Encoded Image . it is crashing , i tried to increasing upto `maxReadLength = 10000` , but still it is not working .

**Reading incoming message**

```
 private func readAvailableBytes(stream: InputStream) {
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxReadLength)

            while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
                let numberOfBytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)

                if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
                    if let _ = inputStream.streamError {
                        break
                    }
                }

           ❌ Crashing in  below line  ❌

               if let reciviedMsg = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer,
                                         length: numberOfBytesRead,
                                         encoding: .ascii,
                                         freeWhenDone: true)
               {
                   delegate?.scoktDidRecivceNewMessagew(message: reciviedMsg)
                }

            }
        }
```

**Error**

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x101890c00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the buffer is allocated only once, but free'd every
time when

```
 String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: numberOfBytesRead, encoding: .ascii, freeWhenDone: true)
```

is called. Here is a short self-contained example demonstrating the problem:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4)
memcpy(buffer, "abcd", 4)

var s = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: 4, encoding: .ascii, freeWhenDone: true)
// OK

s = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: 4, encoding: .ascii, freeWhenDone: true)
// malloc: *** error for object 0x101d8dc40: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Using `freeWhenDone: false` would be one option to solve the problem, but note
that you have to free the buffer eventually.

An alternative is to use an `Array` (or `Data`)  as buffer, this is automatically
released when the function returns. Example:

```
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: maxReadLength)
while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let numberOfBytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)
    if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
        break
    }
    if let receivedMsg = String(bytes: buffer[..<numberOfBytesRead], encoding: .ascii) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i'll try with the solution . sending Base64 encoded Image  over TCP socket is good or bad ?

Comment: `if let receivedMsg = String(bytes: buffer[..<numberOfBytesRead], encoding: .ascii) {  }`  can you please describe this .,,,,, it's not working for me ,,,,   `..<numberOfbytesRead` is giving error `Cannot convert value of type 'PartialRangeUpTo<Int>' to expected argument type 'Int'`

Comment: @Dhiru: The above code compiles without problems in my Xcode 10.

Comment: Ok , i don't know why it is showing error on my Xcode (10.0) 
can you please see this ..  https://imgur.com/a/yMLZnmE

Comment: @Dhiru: Did you define `buffer` as `[UInt8]` array, as I suggested?

Comment: Thanks :)  its solved my current problem . but some of base64 data is getting lost .

Comment: It's a bit sad that this amazing @MartinR answer has only 3 votes. I've chosen the alternative. Thanks!