# Symbolicating crash without crash log file

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

It's not duplicate. My question is how to symbolicate crash error.

My live app is crashing and I've crash report in xCode and crashlytics but I don't have crashlog as it's happening on live app and it's random.

Is it possible to get some meaning out of crash report without a crash log?

How do we find out file & line number from such reports?

Here is one example of such crash

```
crash_info_entry_0
abort() called
crash_info_entry_1
myapp(569,0x16df57000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10404ddae: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer being freed was not allocated \[Swift\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708579/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-swift)

Comment: What's your definition of "crash report" and "crash file"? What's the difference between those two?

Comment: Sorry for confusion about crash file. It's "crash log". I've updated question.

Comment: Then what's your definition of "crash report" and "crash log"? Those two terms are usually synonymous.

Comment: Crash report comes from crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolication is the process of translating addresses into symbols (functions, methods, etc). Without a crash log, which contains those addresses, symbolication doesn't make sense. You cannot translate addresses you do not have. But, where did the output you listed come from? It looks like it could be part of a larger log. You've tagged the issue Crashlytics - did this report come from their service?

There's some helpful information in the logging you've included. The good news is that it is telling you that you've got heap corruption. `malloc` has called `abort` because it's detected an inconsistency with its internal structures. Further, it's extremely unlikely that a symbolicated stack trace would help you, because heap corruption is rarely, if ever, caused by functions further up the stack.

Keep in mind that the crash you are seeing here is an **effect**. To fix this issue, you need a **cause**, and a stack trace isn't going to get you that in this situation.

There's more bad news. It is hard, and often even impossible, to reason about heap corruption. Replicating the bug can also be impossible, as memory corruption is typically not deterministic. As you've noted, the crash appears random. That's because it probably is.

What I would recommend doing here is using the various tools that Apple provides to help debug this kind of issue.

- Look for other crashes that look heap-corruption-related
- Try out `Zombies` in Instruments
- Try malloc scribble, or guardmalloc, two other good memory debugging tools

It is **extremely** common for one heap-corrupting bug to cause lots of different kinds of crashes. This could be an objc over-release, so I'd also keep my eye out for selectorNotRecognized exceptions. Those crashes might give you more of a clue as to what kind of object is being over-released.

Good luck!

Comment: Tx for detailed explanation. Yes it's crashlytics log.